# getting custom attribute values

Tags: reactjs

I have maped an array of objects, each object has doubleclick event which will allow to edit object value. I want to access just the object which was clicked and not all objects. I tried to add a custom property and an if statement which would allow me to access only the slected object, but it didnt worked. How should i solve this problem?

```
       handleDoubleClick = ( event) => {  
      let value = event.target.value;
      let attr = event.target.getAtribute('data-tag');

      if( value === attr ) {   
          this.setState({
           state: setting some states...,

         })
       }

       render()...
       const mapedCargo = cargo.map(cargo => (
      <div key={cargo+cargo.id}>

        <div className="name" key={cargo.id} data-tag={cargo.id} style={styleDiv} onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick}>Cargo Id: {cargo.id}</div> 
          <div style={styleInput}>Cargo Id:
            <input id="test" type="text" defaultValue={cargo.id} />
          </div>               

      </div>
    ))

    return <div className="App">{mapedCargo}</div>

     ...
```

My disered outcome would be:

1st maped object: when you doubleclick on me i turn into input and you can edit me

2nd maped object: you cant edit me if you havnt clicked me

3rd maped object: same logic applies too all objects

and so on...

At the moment when i doubleclick all of the objects react to an event but i want it to react only when selected one is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
handleDoubleClick = ( event, index) => {
  console.log('nuumber ' + index + ' clicked')  
  //other codes
}

const mapedCargo = cargo.map((cargo, index) => (
  <div key={cargo+cargo.id}>
    <div className="name" key={cargo.id} data-tag={cargo.id} style={styleDiv} onDoubleClick={() => {this.handleDoubleClick(event, index)} }>Cargo Id: {cargo.id}</div> 
    <div style={styleInput}>Cargo Id:
      <input id="test" type="text" defaultValue={cargo.id} />
    </div>               
 </div>
```